# Windows Store - Change Windows Phone 8.1 App Name

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store

We tested a application on a test account, and now we want to release it on a production account.

Problem is, we reserved and used the actual name with the test account and we now want to use the same on production account, but it is blocked via our test account.

The application is un-deletable (Microsoft itself wrote article which states that) it can only be hidden.

Therefore I was thinking about reserving a new name in Manage App Names, use it, and then delete the old one. However, I can't figure out how to do this using Visual Studio 2013).

Lets say I have name `X`. I reserved name `Y` in the store (for the same app).

In Visual Studio:

- Right click on `Project -> Properties -> Assembly`, name changed to `Y`
- Display name in `Package.appxmanifest` changed to `Y`

Submitted to store - nothing changed, it still says that app name `X` is in use.

I did not find `App Name` property, but I supposed the assembly is it now?

Because in some older tutorial I saw "app name" at the same position as the Assembly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually fixed it.

I opened file "Package.StoreAssociation.xml" and I changed ReservedName value in bottom of this file to `Y`

I also changed the Package.appxmanifest->Packaging->Packade display name to `Y`

Also if you expand Properties, there is AssemblyInfo, I changed the AssemblyTitle and AssemblyProduct to `Y`

With the thing I already did :

- Right click on `Project -> Properties -> Assembly`, name changed to `Y`
- Display name in `Package.appxmanifest` changed to `Y`

I created bundle and uploaded it as new submission to Windows Store and then publish it. After this, the used reserved name changed from `X` to `Y` and I was able to delete `X` and then reuse him at production account.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for can't be solved in Visual Studio.

My understanding is your have name X reserved on a test account, and you want name X to be on a production account.

This is transferring an app to a different publisher (Test account and Production account are different, hince different publishers even though you own both)

Open a support ticket in the Windows Dev Center, and they should be able to sort this out for you: https://dev.windows.com/en-us

Comment: Thanks for answer, I actually solved (however not the "nice and intuitive" way) :)

Answer (score 1):

For achieving this you need to remove the reserved name from test account and then reserve this name in production account.

For reserving app name in Windows Store first login with the Microsoft account and go to Windows apps dashboard for your account and click on app name to go to app details and on left side click on *App Management* and then click on *Manage app names* here you can reserve a new name and also delete the unused app name. For further information [Check this microsoft link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/mt148539.aspx). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer, however create new name is not problem. The problem is the name I need is actually used, so I cant delete it. And changed it from one name to another is not easy too.